# Permission Denied when doing a Deployment Run in dbt

Tags: dbt

I am trying to deploy the master branch of my dbt repository to create the tables in the production schema. My Data Warehouse is in redshift.
The error that I am getting is "**permission denied for schema**"
I tried running the compiled queries to create these tables from target/run/ directory in dbt. On running these queries in redshift, they run fine without any error. What permissions am I missing that the deployment job is failing to create the tables?

[dbt run failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnW6M.png)

[Database error: permission denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYnRr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Kindly check if you are trying to create a new schema in the code. This is the common mistake all developers do. Check the configuration and change the schema properties
- If you are trying to create in the existing schema, please check the permission of the user from which you are trying to create the table